# Intellij and Eclipse unable to find library artifact

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I've a library project in Android studio that will be used in both Android and Java projects. I'm publishing this library to my own remote artifact repository in both .aar and .jar formats using the maven-publish plugin that's shipped with Android Studio. I can fetch and use the library properly in an Android app however when I try to use it in a Java project, **intellij and eclipse are unable to detect even if the library is there** *even though gradle/maven is fetching the library from the remote repo*. I've tried pushing only aar to the remote repo and fetching that in Java projects but that didn't workout either. Please note that I've no Android dependency/resources in this library. Following is the script being used to generate and push the artifacts to remote server.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "${_groupId}-${_artifactId}-${android.defaultConfig.versionName}.aar"
    }
}

task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier "sources"
}

task deleteOldJar(type:Delete){
    delete 'release/MyLibrary.jar'
}

task exportJar(type:Copy){
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('release/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar','MyLibrary.jar')
}
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url _remoteRepoUrl
        }
    }
    publications {
        library(MavenPublication) {
            groupId _groupId
            artifactId _artifactId
            version android.defaultConfig.versionName
            artifact(sourceJar)
            artifact(exportJar)
            artifact ("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${_groupId}-${_artifactId}-${android.defaultConfig.versionName}.aar") { //aar artifact you want to publish
                builtBy assembleDebug
            }
            //generate pom nodes for dependencies
            pom.withXml {
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.compile.allDependencies.each { dependency ->
                    println "dependency name is: "+dependency.name
                    if(!dependency.name.equals('unspecified')) {
                        def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', dependency.group)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', dependency.name)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', dependency.version)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('type', "aar")
                    }
                    else
                        println "dependency name is unspecified"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Turns out the com.android.library plugin in gradle was somehow messing with the generated artifact such that only Android projects could use the library artifact and not the plain java projects. Since my library doesn't have any layout resources, I can skip making .aar and just generate a jar file. For generating the jar file and publishing it to the remote repo following snippet is being utilized:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

def _remoteRepoUrl = "http://myserver.com/repo"
def _groupId = group
def _versionName = version

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url _remoteRepoUrl
    }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

jar {
    from sourceSets.main.output
}

task jarWithSources(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.output
    if (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.any{it == "publishToMavenLocal"}) {
        from sourceSets.main.allJava
    }
}

// Define how maven-publish publishes to the nexus repository
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url _remoteRepoUrl
        }
    }
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
        // publish the <project> jar as a standalone artifact
        mavenJar(MavenPublication) {
            artifact jarWithSources
            //from components.java -- can't have both the above line and this
            //artifactId "${jar.baseName}_jar"
            version project.version
        }
    }
}

eclipse {
    classpath {
        containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
        containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7'
    }
}
```